# Using UTC in MySQL on website

Tags: mysql, datetime, utc

Should I store all datetime's in MySQL database in UTC?
(Using UTC_TIMESTAMP())

How can I display datetime to user, if I don't know user's timezone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using UTC is usually a good bet, particularly if you're dealing with logical "instants in time" (such as timestamps for creating entries etc).

As for how you display them to your user: if you don't know the time zone, you can't display a date/time to the user sensibly *however* you store it, so this is really separate from the UTC decision. One option could be to use Javascript to convert from UTC to local time. Another possibility is to allow the user to specify the time zone themselves.

Comment: If you need to do time zone conversion in your SQL, it's pretty easy with the `convert_tz` function, but you have to import the time zone database first: See also http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz

Comment: @Joe: I'd generally suggest doing the time zone conversion rather closer to the presentation layer, to be honest.

Comment: Generally I agree, especially for interactive applications which may be the main use case for the OP. But for running ad hoc queries and even certain business functions or reporting, if you're storing everything UTC timestamps, knowing how to do the conversion in MySQL is convenient too.  For example, what if you want to send a text message alert to a user at a certain date/time and there is 'presentation layer' per se?

Comment: Anyway, I didn't mean to hijack your answer, but didn't feel my contribution was worth its own answer